# How to add subcaption the the subfigure

Tags: captions, subcaption, subfig

I need to add sub caption for the image how can do that?

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering

\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{im1.PNG}
  
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.29\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{im2.png}
  
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{im3.png}
  
\endminipage
 \caption{The device}
 \label{fig: T devices}
\end{figure}
```

This is the output for the code, I need to add  the image name under each image(caption for each image)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a compilable example - that's much more useful than a snippet of code. That said, you may be looking for the `subcaption` package if I'm guessing correctly that you're already using `caption`.

Comment: If you are using subcaption, subfigure IS a minipage with subcaptions.  Also, `\caption` starts and ends wil a `\par`.

Comment: I updated my question, any answer please?

Answer (score 2):

If your subcaption is just a notation underneath each image, consider using a `tabular`-like setup (using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) like below, or otherwise).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C C C @{}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
    \small Here is a subcaption &
      &
      \small Another subcaption that spans multiple lines
   \end{tabularx}
 \caption{The device}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use a `tabular` sets the content in a row-like fashion, which allows for separate alignments of your images (if they have differing proportions) and subcaptions (if they are of differing lengths). For example, you can have a baseline or bottom-alignment of the images, and a top-alignment of the subcaptions.

Comment: I got on this error Package tabularx Warning: X Columns too narrow (table too wide) on input line 265.
Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.
Overfull \hbox (700.0pt too wide) in alignment at lines 265--265
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Comment: And what about the caption of B image?

Comment: @stella: Did you add the `\newcolymntype{C}{...}` segment to your preamble? You can add a caption for the second image, sure!

Comment: Ok, now it works. But I need to add caption to the image in the middle, how can I do that?  and I need to resize the image, How can I use some thing like this  \minipage{0.29\textwidth}  ?

Comment: @stella: See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/qM5uRwx0) for a middle subcaption. In terms of resizing content, you should use the key-value options supplied by [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics`: `\includegraphics[height=2em]{...}`, for example.